# Error when copying bytes - offset and length were out of bounds.

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion, byte, buffer

I've trying to convert a 2D array of values to a byte[] and back into the original 2D array. When running my code I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in TestProject.exe.

Additional information: Offset and length were out of bounds 
for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from the 
index to the end of the source collection.
```

Here's my code:

```
    byte[,] dataArray = new byte[,] {
        {4, 6, 2},
        {0, 2, 0},
        {1, 3, 4}
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value[" + i + ", " + j + "] = " + dataArray[j, i]);
        }
    }
    long byteCountArray = dataArray.GetLength(0) * dataArray.GetLength(1) * sizeof(byte);

    var bufferByte = new byte[byteCountArray];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(dataArray, 0, bufferByte, 0, bufferByte.Length);

    //Here is where I try to convert the values and print them out to see if the  values are still the same:

    byte[] originalByteValues = new byte[bufferByte.Length / 2];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferByte, 0, originalByteValues, 0, bufferByte.Length);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Values---: " + originalByteValues[i]);
    }
```

The error occurs on the Buffer.BlockCopy line:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferByte, 0, originalByteValues, 0, bufferByte.Length);
```

I'm new to programming/conversion with bytes, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are making the array too small, half the size you are trying to copy

```
new byte[bufferByte.Length / 2];
```

seems it should be

```
new byte[bufferByte.Length];
```

Comment: Wow - rookie mistake on my part. Thanks.